# How to show an alert message when no form field is used in 30 minutes using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a form with couple of input fields and i want a script that will show a pop up message IF no field is used after a certain time-frame, asking "Are you still there?" or something like that.

Is it possible? Please advice, thanks!

Comment: can you provide with some code that you have tried

Comment: @3nigma not yet tried any code, i am searching one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full sample in JsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Zsjtn/

What I recommend is using setTimeOut to call a method that you want to display a message or do whatever action you wanted to do. Then on change event on all your input types try to reset the TimeOut. Here is JS Code that simulates this scenario:

```
// Timer for 3 seconds to call formTimeOut function 
var _timer = setTimeout("formTimeOut()",3000);

$(function(){

    // Monitor Value change of Inputs in your HTML
    $("input").change(function(){

        // Clear previous timer 
        clearTimeout(_timer);
        // Reset the timer to re-run after 3 seconds.
        _timer = setTimeout("formTimeOut()",3000);

    });
});

// This is the function that will run after time out
function formTimeOut(){

    // Timeout Logic goes here
    alert("Are you there?");
}
```

You can change $("input") to any criteria that may fit your project.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers, at least give the code in your post and explain what you've done as needed.

Comment: I was just adding the code!!! Also JsFiddle is used to share codes where actually simulates the answer and easy to undrestand.

Comment: Yes, but think of people who come here from search engines, rather then seeing the code in the answer, with an added link to an example, they might miss your answer altogether. -1 to +1 :)

Comment: @Truth, Thanks for your vote :-) I totally agree with you. I usually post JsFiddle first to help the person asap and sharp after that I start adding more info to it. I saw the same behavior with others in this community.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to start a timer for thirty minutes and attach a `change` event to all of your fields. On change, you want to erase the current timer, and create a new one for another 30 minutes.

For example, it would be something like this:

```
$('input[type=text]').bind('change', function (e) {
    // .. Triggered every time a form text field is changed
    // .. Do stuff here
});
```

And for the timer, you'd just use `settimeout`

Comment: Cool idea, i am new to this change event, can you give me any examples of this change event? Thanks!

Comment: Updated with example. You can also use the `.change` method in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/change/ will give you examples of how to use it as well.

Comment: many thanks @ktash I am taking a look into this now. Seems very helpful.

Comment: @Ktash you should be using `.on` rather then `.bind` it's a more updated method.

Comment: @Truth depends on his version of jQuery. `.on()` is new to 1.7 and I didn't want to assume he had the most recent version. So I went with `.bind()` to be safe

Comment: Still worth a mention though ;)